# Can I subscribe to a listener without having a class object of the calling class?

Tags: c#, events, .net-core, event-handling

According to the [tutorial from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events), I need a `object of the class` when I want to `listen to a event`. **(C# .NET Core 2.2)**

**Is it somehow possible without having a instance of the calling object?**

My situation is that I have a `listener` listen on a `RabbitMQ`. When data come in I process the data through a long way of objects.

**Here a description:**

`Object a` creates new `Object b` and passes data, `Object b` creates `Object c` and passes data,..., `Object z` is saving data. At `Object a` inside my listener from `RabbidMQ`. 
I need to know information from saving on `Object z` (works, don't works, works partially).

**What is the best way to get my response information back into the `Object a`?**

Comment: This question is difficult to read. You might get better/more responses if you make it clearer

Comment: @RobertPerry read now, is it clear ?

Comment: @FrankMehlhop welcome, please always try to succinctly provide the crux and optimize the unnecessary details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Code that you have posted**

It is simple `Event Handler`, which is a wrapper over a delegate and can be made to subscribe any any number of methods `(Multi Cast delegate)`, which is trigger, when ever event is invoked with all methods in the chain executing, by notifying all the listeners.

> **When does this kind of code works**

It can only work inside a `process / memory`, not across the process, which means you cannot subscribe for the notification across the network call or call across the process boundary, since that needs serialization / deserialization, even when you can serialize objects / data and recreate, but not the subscription logic / function call  / logical processing

> **Your Question ?**

I am not sure if I got everything, but following is my understanding, you have subscribed to `Rabbit MQ`, which does notify your code, when new data comes in, which is their client and server code across the network, all the other objects A-Z are in same memory then all you need to do is pass on the Event object to all the relevant object, since delegates internally behave like a function pointer, so you can execute it from anywhere, till the point object is valid it will execute the same method as you expect, but you need to pass same object, if state is important, you cannot create a new object and expect it to maintain the state. If state is not a concern, then create an object from anywhere, though generally state has relevance in such cases.

> **For across Network**

In MS world exist `Signal R`, but there multiple implementation as in the case of Rabbit MQ they all provide hooks to notify any subscriber over the network

Comment: Not across the network, it's all in one application.
So your answer is in short words that there is no other solution than the example from Microsoft plus passing the object through objects B-Y?!

Comment: Yes exactly you keep passing the reference and anything added to that delegate / event will be executed when the delegate is invoked. In reality if you don't have a state even that is not required, you can directly call the method using the passed object but its always expected that there will be state and along the way other methods / listeners might have subscribed, which final invocation class might not be aware, and all of them need to be notified / executed. In fact delegates can be independent of all the classes, since they subscribe by signature.